# Nil Swift Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, null

My dictionary is always nil, would like to understand why this is happening.
My code:

```
var dic = [NSDate : MCACalendar]?()
dic?[currentDate!] = calendar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `[NSDate : MCACalendar]?()` fails and returns `nil`. You probably want to use:

```
var dic = [NSDate : MCACalendar]?([:])
```

or

```
var dic: [NSDate : MCACalendar]? = [:]
```

Comment: I got the error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: As error states you unwrapped something that is `nil`. What was the line that was crashing?

Comment: the line: "tempDic?[currentDate!] = calendar"

Comment: I guess that `currentDate` is `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

@Kirsteins provides the solution - but it's good to know why.

Using `[NSDate : MCACalendar]?()` doesn't work as you expect because it creates an instance of `[NSDate : MCACalendar]?`, i.e. an instance of an optional - to be more precise, an instance of `Optional<[NSDate : MCACalendar]>`. So that initialization doesn't create an instance of `[NSDate : MCACalendar]`.

Creating an instance of an optional (`Optional<T>`) using the parameterless constructor initializes it to `.None` (equivalent to `nil`), so for example in:

```
var x = Int?() // `x` is initialized as `.None`
```

If a parameter is passed to the constructor, then the optional variable is initialized with `.Some`:

```
var x = Int?(5) // x is initialized as `.Some(5)`
```

That explains Kirsteins's solution no. 1. Solution no. 2 is so obvious that it doesn't need further explanation :)